# Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, web-applications

At the moment I am developing a website while using the Playframework2. I am just a beginner in programming. I read some books about exceptions but now in the real world , exception handling is really strange.

To be honest I don't really care what exceptions are thrown I handle all exceptions the same way.
`return badrequest();` . I only use exceptions for logging.

```
try{
...
}
catch(Exeption e){
//log
return badrequest();
}
```

But this is so much boilerplate and it's really annoying to write, because every method throws the same exceptions.

Any tips , hints or resources that you could give me?

edit:

An example would be my "global" config file. Because I need to connect to the db every time I thought i could write a singleton for this problem.

```
private Datastore connect() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException,
            DbAuthException {

        Mongo m = new Mongo(dbUrl, dbPort);
        Datastore ds = new Morphia().createDatastore(m, dbName);
        boolean con = ds.getDB().authenticate(username, password.toCharArray());
        if (!con)
            throw new DbAuthException();
        return ds;
    }
```

This also results in a try and catch every time I want to connect to the db. My problem is I don't think I can handle them diffidently.

A code example :

```
public static Result addComment(String title) {
        try {

            Datastore ds = DatabaseConnect.getInstance().getDatastore();
            Form<Comment> filledForm = commentForm.bindFromRequest();
            Comment userComment = filledForm.get();
            userComment.setUsername(Util.getUsernameFromSession(ctx()));
            User.increasePointsBy(ctx(), 1);
            UserGuides.addComment(title, userComment);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return badRequest();
        }
        return redirect(routes.Guides.blank());
    }
```

In this case I was to lazy to write the same try and catch over and over again, and this is duplicated code.

Maybe there is a book that explains how to design a big application with exception handling?

Comment: Tips, hints or resources with regard to what exactly? Web applications should handle exceptions gracefully (if you don't need to terminate).

Comment: I'm not sure which IDE you are using, however if you are using eclipse, you can also use "code templates" to help speed up your efforts. Normally, you want to try to avoid repeat code, if possible, however in some cases you can't and code templates can help speed up the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke a method, you do not necessarily have to catch the exceptions right there. You can let your callers handle them (declaring a throws clause if it is a checked exception). In fact, the ability to pass them on to the callers without any additional work is the distinguishing feature of exceptions.

My team has adopted the following coding standard: We throw checked exceptions for those rare cases when we want to recover from a failure, and unchecked exceptions for anything else. There is only a single catch block for the unchecked exceptions in a method so high in the call stack that all requests pass through it (for instance in a `ServletFilter`). This catch block logs the exception, and forwards the user to the "Sorry, this shouldn't have happened" page.

Comment: +1 for advice to use an *exception barrier*, way to go. Side note: this approach does involve a boilerplate `try { ... } catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }` around any code declaring checked exceptions.

Comment: Oh... yeah I am stupid. If i could pass them to a higher instance I would only have to catch them once. Yeah this makes more sense.

Comment: Maik, that's the beauty of the exception mechanism. In fact, that's precisely why it exists in the first place, instead of passing error information by return value, like C. It's a great shame what didactic damage the checked exceptions have made, forcing the unwary developer to deal with the exception on the spot, usually in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at your code to examine why you're throwing all these exceptions? Exceptions are there for a reason- to tell you that something went wrong. If you're writing too much "boilerplate" `try-catch` code and you're not in a thousand line application, you have to refactor.

`try-catch` can be irritating when you have a complex block and can become very monotonous and boilerplate ([Marc Gravell even said he usually uses `try-finally`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11596066/451590)) but as a new programmer, it would be helpful for you to examine the code that you write and figure out how to either handle or avoid those exceptions.

As akf mentions, ignoring exceptions can also be hazardous to debugging. It will be harder to track down where something catastrophic went wrong if you're missing exceptions leading up to it.

Comment: I would add that simply ignoring the Exception is very bad practice. You should at least print it to a log or you will have no trace of the real problem w/i your code

Comment: @akf Thanks, I've added a portion to my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my post. At the moment I only catch the general Exception. And then I log all these exceptions, but this is still duplicated code

Comment: @MaikKlein: Catch the specific exceptions that are recoverable and handle them appropriately. Don't catch general exceptions and move on as if nothing happened.

Comment: @MaikKlein If you're making a database connection call every function, I'd push the error handling down to that function and exit gracefully there. If not, then you can either let your application die because of a failed DB connection or catch it and display an error message.